# Common Lisp special variable scope different for defmethod and defun?

Tags: common-lisp, scope

either I'm missing something very stupid or the scope of special variables is unexpectedly different for defmethod and defun (tested using SBCL 1.1.14):

1. As expected:

   ```
   (defun ttprint-object (prefix out)
     (format out "~A: in defun: < ~A >~%" prefix *print-readably*))
   (let ((*print-readably* t))
     (format t "let: calling defun: < ~A >~%" *print-readably*)
     (ttprint-object "from let" t))

   let: calling defun: < T >
   from let: in defun: < T >
   ```
2. With let defmethod works different from defun, so unexpected:

   ```
   (defclass empty () ())

   (defmethod print-object ((self empty) out)
     (format out "in defmethod: < ~A >~%" *print-readably*)
     (ttprint-object "from defmethod" out))

   (let ((*print-readably* t))
     (ttprint-object "from let" t)
     (format t "let: calling defmethod: < ~A >~%" *print-readably*)
     (format t "let: ~A" (make-instance 'empty)))

   from let: in defun: < T >
   let: calling defmethod: < T >
   let: in defmethod: < NIL >
   from defmethod: in defun: < NIL >
   ```
3. Also with setf defmethod works different from defun but same as with let:

   ```
   (progn
     (setq *print-readably* t)
     (ttprint-object "from setf" t)
     (format t "setf: calling defmethod: < ~A >~%" *print-readably*)
     (format t "setf: ~A" (make-instance 'empty)))

   from setf: in defun: < T >
   setf: calling defmethod: < T >
   setf: in defmethod: < NIL >
   from defmethod: in defun: < NIL >
   ```

Hopefully it's me...

Thanks in advance, Frank

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`~A` binds `*print-readably*` to false (emphasis added):

> #### [22.3.4.1 Tilde A: Aesthetic](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cda.htm)
>
> An arg, any object, is printed without escape characters (as by princ). If arg is a string, its characters will be output verbatim. If arg is nil it will be printed as nil; the colon modifier (~:A) will cause an arg of nil to be printed as (), but if arg is a composite structure, such as a list or vector, any contained occurrences of nil will still be printed as nil.
>
> …
>
> **`~A` binds `*print-escape*` to false, and `*print-readably*` to false.**

When you do

```
(format t "let: ~A" (make-instance 'empty))
```

the `~A` directive binds `*print-readably*` to false (i.e., `nil`), and eventually the Lisp writer calls the `print-object` method for the object.  If you don't want this binding, you might try `~W` which doesn't modify the printer variables:

> #### [22.3.4.3 Tilde W: Write](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cdc.htm)
>
> An argument, any object, is printed obeying every printer control
>   variable (as by write). In addition, ~W interacts correctly with depth
>   abbreviation, by not resetting the depth counter to zero. ~W does not
>   accept parameters. If given the colon modifier, ~W binds
>   `*print-pretty*` to true. If given the at-sign modifier, ~W binds `*print-level*` and `*print-length*` to nil.
>
> ~W provides automatic support for the detection of circularity and
>   sharing. If the value of `*print-circle*` is not nil and ~W is applied
>   to an argument that is a circular (or shared) reference, an
>   appropriate #n# marker is inserted in the output instead of printing
>   the argument.

If you use `~W`, you get the results you'd originally expected:

```
CL-USER> (let ((*print-readably* t))
               (ttprint-object "from let" t)
               (format t "let: calling defmethod: < ~A >~%" *print-readably*)
               (format t "let: ~w" (make-instance 'empty)))
    from let: in defun: < T >
    let: calling defmethod: < T >
    let: in defmethod: < T >
    from defmethod: in defun: < T >
```

Comment: D'oh - talking about "least surprise", especially since consequences are different for defmethod and defun. And thanks a lot for the quick and exhaustive answer, very welcome!

Comment: It's not the difference between `defmethod` and `defun`, though;  it's that `~a` binds `*print-readably*` to false, and that for objects, `~a` calls the corresponding `print-object` method.  The only real surprise is that `format` binds one value and causes another method to be called, and in this case, that method depended on the value that `format` bound.